# Deployment issue facing in vercel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemailer, vercel

I have used nodemailer in backend for sending mail. But when i use the local host link on my frontend I receive email. But when i use vercel deployed link, email is not receiving.

Even though in vercel log, vercel is showing me that response is 200 and email is sent.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyhnp.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrPGZ.png)

please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you kept your API key in the .env file?

Comment: The issue likely lies in Nodemailer. It can be either failing silently or it is not sending anything before the function finishes execution. Also, remember that you need to use Nodemailer with a service as Serverless Functions cannot send emails Check https://vercel.com/guides/sending-emails-from-an-application-on-vercel